# Access AngularJS scope from Directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to access a scope variable defined in the app controller so i can update on a click event from Directive i've created, but it doesn't seem to be able to access the global scope from its isolated scope.

the scope variable is defined (currentTitle):

```
app.controller('news', function($scope, $http, $timeout) {
$scope.promise = $timeout(function() { //This is here just to mock the asynchronous loading of the data
$scope.articles = [{
  title: 'Article 1',
  content: 'It works!'
}, {
  title: 'Article 2',
  content: 'It still works'
}]
}, 3000);

$scope.currentTitle = "my - title";
$scope.showDetails = false;
});
```

and the scope defined in the directive is:

```
scope: {
  //bind the showDetails into the scope so it can be seen by all of the accordion elements
  promise: '&?',
  currentTitle: '=?',
  showDetails: '=?bind'
}
```

here is a codePen that contains all the code: http://codepen.io/valecarlos/pen/bpmryw

What i want to do, is to update the header title, when one of the  titles is clicked, for now i'm just trying to hardcode an update on the scope's `currentTitle` variable and `$apply`-inside the click event in the directive-, but i don't see it reflected on the header's title.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting your `currentTitle` key on your directive scope to this. It will create a 2-way binding allowing you to easily change the `currentTitle` in your parent controller from your directive's scope.

JS

```
  scope: {
    ...
    currentTitle: '=',
    ...
  },
```

HTML

```
         <accordion promise="promise" current-title="currentTitle">
            <!--<dt ng-repeat-start="article in articles" ng-class="showDetails ? 'show-titles' : 'show-titles-not'">.-->
            <dt ng-repeat-start="article in articles" ng-class="{'show-titles' : showDetails}">
            <div class="grid-30">
                <div class="round-div"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="grid-70">
                <h5>{{article.title}}</h5>
            </div>

            </dt>
            <dd ng-repeat-end="" ng-class="{'show-titles' : showDetails}">
                <div class="grid-40">
                    <img src={{article.image}} alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="grid-60">
                    <div class="news-desc">
                        <h5>
                            {{article.title}}
                        </h5>
                        <p>
                            {{article.content}}
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </dd>
        </accordion>
```

Comment: Thank you!, I had tried setting the currentTitle: to '=', but i was totally missing the definition in the HTML tag to complete the 2 way binding, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

If you pass in a function with the "&" syntax, you should be able to call it within the directive.

Let's assume the function in the controller looks like this:

```
$scope.someFunction = function(someParameter) {...}
```

Then your directive will look like this:

```
...
    scope {
      someFunction: "&"
   }
...
//in link or controller
$scope.someFunction({someParameter:'foo'});
```

Comment: thanks! i've change it to `currentTitle: '&',` but it doesn't work either, maybe because it's not a function but a variable?

Comment: Yes, your function in the parent scope would then take the variable you pass to the function and make the change on its own scope. Alternatively, $emit an event. Or don't use an isolate scope.